# Partial bold text in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

This is how I am adding asp.net label,

```
<asp:Label ID="lblFruitNameAndDate" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:Label>
```

In JavaScript I am trying this,

```
  $("#lblFruitNameAndDate").text(webServiceData.FruitName + " '<b> On: " + webServiceData.FruitCrateDate + "</b>");
```

but on screen i am getting `<b>` tags.

Comment: have you tried using `.html` instead of `.text` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `.text()` method doesn't accept arguments, its used for getting the text value not setting it, here are the jquery docs [on `.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

You'd need to use `.html()` which does [set dom content/elements](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

```
    $("#lblFruitNameAndDate").html(
        webServiceData.FruitName + " '<b> On: " + webServiceData.FruitCrateDate + "</b>"
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

A demonstration of bold method can be found at W3Schools like this:

```
document.write("<p>Bold: " + txt.bold() + "</p>");
```

and you should also consider that bold() method is not standard, and may not work as expected in all browsers.

Comment: using document.write gives you no control over where the text is output

Comment: I was rferring particularly to the .bold()  method because that's why he's getting the <b> tags.

Comment: not correct, if you "".bold() in your console, it gives you the 'b' tags. The jquery method being used is wrong, its not inserting into the dom correctly, so the text '<b>' is being shown on the screen

Comment: I will check this out, anyway using <b> is not recommended, use <strong> instead.